# Fetch selected items from Two Sided Multi Select Control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, linq

I have a multi select control similar to the one in below page -

http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/twosidedmultiselect.html

It works cool. The only challenge I am facing is how to smartly get the selected items.I assume some linq queries will help me, but I am new to this -

Form example,

1) If we add a new item in our selection -

```
prevSelection = {item1,item2}
newSelection ={item1,item2,item3}
```

How to find out that only item3 is newly added in newSelection?

2) If we remove an item in our selection -

```
prevSelection = {item1,item2}
newSelection ={item1}
```

How to find out that item2 is deleted in newSelection?

3) More challenging, if we remove as well as add few item in our selection -

```
prevSelection = {item1,item2}
newSelection ={item3,item4}
```

How to find out that item1 and item2 is deleted from newSelection, and item3,item4 added in newSelection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
var newItems = newSelection.Except(prevSelection);
```

2)

```
var deletedItems = prevSelection.Except(newSelection);
```

3)

```
var newItems = newSelection.Except(prevSelection);
var deletedItems = prevSelection.Except(newSelection);
```